# Python: Iterating a conditional statement within a loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop

So I have a list of values called `temp_data` and I have imported two functions I want to use, which are:

```
# Function which converts from fahr to celsius
def fahr_to_celsius(temp_fahrenheit):
    converted_temp = (temp_fahrenheit - 32)/ 1.8 # Now we have assigned the convertable number to the variable
    return converted_temp

def temp_classifier(temp_celsius): #Function name temp_classifier, parameter temp_celsius that we later use to define the temperature
    if temp_celsius <-2: #Classifies temperatures below -2 degrees (Celsius) and returns value 0
        return 0
    elif (temp_celsius >-2) and (temp_celsius <2): #Classifies temperatures equal or higher than -2 up to +2 degrees (Celsius) and returns value 1
        return 1
    elif (temp_celsius >=2) and (temp_celsius <15): #Classifies temperatures equal or higher than +2 up to +15 degrees (Celsius) and returns value 2
        return 2
    elif temp_celsius >15: #Classifies temperatures equal or higher than +15 degrees (Celsius) and returns value 3
        return 3
```

The first function works well where I iterate over the values of `temp_data` and convert them to celsius with the output of `temp_celsius`. The output of being

```
for t in temp_data: #Takes the iteration data from temp_data
    temp_celsius=(fahr_to_celsius(t)) #Assigns output to variable
    print(temp_celsius)
```

output:

```
-7.222222222222222
-6.111111111111111
-6.111111111111111
-6.111111111111111
-5.0
```

and so on (336 values).

But then when I want to use these variables of `temp_celsius` in the other function `temp_classifier` I get the error `'float' object is not iterable`.

```
for t in temp_celsius: #Takes the iteration data from temp_data
    temp_class=(temp_classifier(t)) #Assigns output to variable
    print(temp_class)
```

What am I doing wrong here? The goal is to assign the outputs of the first function `temp_celsius` to the categories of the other function `temp_classifier`.

Comment: What is `temp_celsius`? Is it an iterable of floats or is it a float, already?

Comment: It's the variable to which I assigned conversion from fahrenheits (int) to celsius and the result is a list of floats.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you print out `print(type(temp_celsius))` and `print(temp_celsius)` before calling `temp_celsius` in the last code snippet (i.e. before iterating over it)?

Comment: Outputs are then:
<class 'float'>
-2.2222222222222223 
So it appears the temp_celsius is only inside the loop a list

Comment: just some side notes: the parentheses in your `elif` statements are unnecessary, also `temp_classifier(t)` is enough. And you could make your code much more readable by adding spaces before and after operators, e.g.: `< -2` is better than `<-2`. It's more clear that the minus sign belongs to the number and that it's not syntactic sugar like `>=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're iterating over a float instead floats saved in an iterable object, e.g. a list.

```
for t in temp_celsius: # Make sure temp_celsius is an iterable
    temp_class = temp_classifier(t)
    print(temp_class)
```

or calling directly the float without iteration if you're only interested in converting one value:

```
temp_class = temp_classifier(t)
    print(temp_class)
```

Comment: Yeah I just understood that before you posted this, thank you!

Comment: Yes, just wanted to make sure to understand you right, before posting an answer which is helpful also for others (they can see now it's solved).